# Can I install a localized certificate authority in Windows XP?

Tags: certificate

We are a division of a much larger organization and this organization uses Novell domain authentication.  The entire division uses Windows XP.  We'd like to implement digital signing of our Office documents.

Is it possible to install a certificate authority service in one of our XP machines and then configure our division's XP machines to validate signatures with that?  If so, what CA service software runs on XP?

I just would like to consider this direction instead of an enormous organization-wide implementation and instead of involving enormous IT resources.

Comment: Is running a linux box/VM not an option?  Tinyca is prettyeasy to use, but *nix based.